# How to use advanced vim copy selections methods in TMUX

Tags: vim, tmux, copy-paste, selection

I'm using **vim** and **tmux** and I am interested if there is a way to use something like advanced vim selection methods in tmux.

So for example if I have a text in **vim**

```
This is a sentence "and I want to copy inside quotes" 
Anoteher sentence (and I want to copy inside quotes)
```

In **vim** I would simply run `yi"` (first sentence) and `yi)` (second sentence)

Wheres in **tmux** I can really use very basic "selection vi-like" marking/selection.

Any ideas ?
Thx

Comment: I had the same wish but couldn't find a way (I'm sure you already know the method: `F"yt"` to [F]ind quote, [y]ank u[t]ill quote).